# Relating Norm and Measure for doing calculus.

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, normed-spaces

In $\mathbb{R}$, integration and differentiation are complementary to each other but as we make our definition more abstract the differ, as to define integration we need a measure space and to define derivative we need vector space with norm. These requirements are disjoint and may not always occurs together (Note once we defined each of the entities mentioned above, we can talk of anti integral or anti derivative resp as the inverse process). But I was wondering if given an measure space, can we define derivative by constructing a norm based on the measure specified (for integral) such that the anti-integral and derivative are compatible.

Some comment/remark/insight will be helpful

Comment: Radon-Nikodym derivation is a theory of derivation linked with the Lebesgue integration theory

Comment: @SolubleFish Pardon my ignorance, but I thought Radon-Nikodym as kind of anti-integral theorem i.e if given $\mu$ and $\nu$ find $f$ such that $fd\mu = d\nu$ whereas I am interested in having a derivative kind of interpretation, ie $|g(x+y)-g(x)|/|y|$ and want to find the construction of the norm $| |$ from given measure  (and also that $g' d\mu = d\nu$

Comment: $f$ is often writen $f = \frac{\text{d}\nu}{\text{d}\mu}$, for a reason

Comment: On a general measure space, there is not $+$ to define $x+y$

Comment: What are you trying to differentiate? Are you thinking about the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: @OliverDiaz I was trying to extend the ideas of fundamental theorem of calculus to more general space.  To simplify we have a concept of integration on measure space and differenciation (say Frechet differention) on Banach Space. So I was thinking can we induce a norm from a measure (and vice versa) so that these two (kind of) become inverses of each other.

Comment: @SolubleFish I am still not clear. Your last comment that + is not defined in a measure space is exactly the point i want to raise i.e. can we give a vector space and norm construction based on $\mu$ such that $f$ of raydon nikodym is same as (say Frechet derivative of $g_{\mu}$ where $g$ is a function defined via $\mu$)

Comment: I don't think there is much hope to build the vector space structure from just the measure

Comment: If you you are not clear in what you want (or what problem you are trying to solve) then the answers will be varied and not cohesive. For example, the space of (signed) measures of finite total variation from a Banach space. Then one can talk about differentiation of functions on measures If you want something similar to the fundamental theorem of calculus, then there is the notion of differentiation of a measure with respect another measure (Random Nikodym derivative being one example). But all this is not useful if you don't have a specific example or problem you are trying to solve.